# How to show $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I would like to show that
$$
\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2) = \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}).
$$

Can you say me what is a good way to show that? My idea is to show it via generators of these both $\sigma$-algebras, namely
$$
\Sigma^2:=\left\{\times_{i=1}^2 (a_i,b_i]: a_i,b_i\in\mathbb{R}, a_i\leq b_i\right\}
$$
as generator for $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and
$$
\mathfrak{Z}:=\bigcup_{S\in\mathcal{E}(\left\{1,2\right\})}\left\{\times_{i\in\left\{1,2\right\}}B_i: B_i\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}), i\in S; B_i=\mathbb{R}, i\in\left\{1,2\right\}\setminus S\right\}
$$
as generator for $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ where $\mathcal{E}(\left\{1,2\right\})$ is the set of the finite subsets of $\left\{1,2\right\}$.

---

So my idea is to show $\Sigma^2\subset\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathfrak{Z}\subset\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

I think $\Sigma^2\subset\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, because for any $(a_1,b_1]\times (a_2,b_2]$ in $\Sigma^2$ it is $(a_1,b_1]\times (a_2,b_2]=\pi_1^{-1}((a_1,b_1])\cap\pi_2^{-1}((a_2,b_2])\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, where $\pi_i$ is the i-th canonical projection.

Is that ok? What's with the other inclusion?

Comment: I think it might be easier to show that $\{ (a,b)\times (c,d) \}$ generates both $\sigma$-algebras.